# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Status'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

To do logistic regression on python, this is my code below:

Imported Dataset:[Facebook Metrics](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Facebook+metrics)

```
# Load dataset
url = "dataset_Facebook.csv"
dataset1 = pandas.read_csv(url, sep = ";", header = 0)


# Split-out validation dataset
array = dataset1.values
X = array[:,0:4]
Y = array[:,4]
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)


# Test options and evaluation metric
seed = 7
scoring = 'accuracy'


# Spot Check Algorithms
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = np.log10(model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring))
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

When compiling the program, i get these sets of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ernestsoo/Desktop/WESTWORLD (Season 01) DUB 720/Assignment2.JackyTen.ErnestSoo/assignment2.py", line 93, in <module>
    cv_results = np.log10(model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 140, in cross_val_score
    for train, test in cv_iter)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 758, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 608, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 571, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 109, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 238, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 1173, in fit
    order="C")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 521, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Status'
```

Because it seem like a DataType problem, i tried parsing the value from the dataset to float:

```
array = float(dataset1.values)
```

But this is not working.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What part of Python would need to regress, for you to be able to measure logistic regression on python? Are you working with the (C) source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Status'`

This error means that at some point **your code is trying to convert the string 'Status' to float**. Casting your data to float won't solve the problem. The problem is that your code is trying to cast something it shouldn't.

If you execute that code: `float("Hello")` it raise `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Hello'`. Use the error information to debug your code. Try to find where the *"Status"* string is given where a float is expected.

Hope it will help you to debug your code